# When I resize the parent UIView, the child view bounds size changes unexpectedly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have programmatically created a parent view that contains two subviews. At some point, a third child view is added between the two original child views and the parent is resized accordingly:

```
_childView1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0, 320.0, 320.0)];
_childView2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, _childView1.frame.size.height, 320.0, 320.0)];
_parentView = = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, _childView1.frame.size.height+_childView2.frame.size.height)];
[_parentView addSubview: _childView1];
[_parentView addSubview: _childView2];
[self.view addSubview:_parentView];
...
// Later on...
_childView3 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, _childView1.frame.size.height, 320.0, 162)];
[_parentView insertSubview:_childView3 belowSubview: _childView2];

// Resize the parent view
_parentView.frame = CGRectMake(_parentView.frame.origin.x, _parentView.frame.origin.y, _parentView.frame.size.width, _parentView.frame.size.height+_childView3.frame.size.height);
// [_childView1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0, 320.0, 320.0)]; // (1)
// [_childView1 setBounds:CGRectMake(0.0, 0, 320.0, 320.0)]; // (2)

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.8 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat animations:^{
[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:1];

// Shift the second child view down to accommodate the third view
_childView2.frame = CGRectMake(_childView2.frame.origin.x, _childView2.frame.origin.y+_childView3.frame.size.height+3, _childView2.frame.size.width, _childView2.frame.size.height);
        }completion:nil];
```

I was expecting childView1 to stay anchored to the top edge of the parentView, while childView2 animate scrolling down.

Instead, the bounds.size.height of childView1 is increased by childView3 (320+162). It's almost like some padding is added to the top of childView1.

Interestingly, everything works as expected if I reset the frame.size of childView1 to its original size uncommenting (1). But I don't think this is the best solution to the problem.
Resetting the bounds.size (uncommenting (2)) there is no improvement.

Is there some auto layout setting that I need to disable to keep childView1 anchored to the top border of the parentView?

Comment: A view's frame won't change unless you change it, with a few exceptions, none of which appear in your code

Comment: My instinct is that you have other code that changes the frame, and it's running but you don't think it is running.

Comment: Indeed I think the problem was that I had this line somewhere else: _childView1.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight; Removing this seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: Yeah, that would do it.

Comment: try to use view.clipToBounds property.